# How do i add more elements to a structured array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to add more elements dynamically to an array that has a named structure, I have (this works):

```
var v = [{
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}];
```

It initializes the structure with 1 element with 2 values, but, I want to add more elements later in the page, something like:

```
v.x.push(2); // something like this would insert a new element and give value of 2 to x of the new element.
```

Can anyone help me with this, using pure JavaScript? Thanks.

Comment: do you want to add value to existing property of the object or to add new properties such as `z: 0`?

Comment: add more x values, and more y values, i want to save coordinates, its like having an array of coordinates

Comment: I don't think you can do it with native JS methods. IMO best solution would be some abstracted function i.e. `const pushCoord = (coordArr, coordObj = {}) => [...coordArr, { x: 0, y: 0, ...coordObj}]` - this handles case if there is only one coordinate given and defaults other to 0 (or if there are no arguments given)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JavaScript [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method, *e.g.*

```js
let v = [{
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}];
v.push({
  x: 2
});
console.log(v);
```